# use of class RandomVelocityPrivatePlugin class

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hii,
May I know the need to make the class RandomVelocityPrivatePlugin in the source of RnadomVelcoity Plugin?
Is it just a default class for the cases, when user doesn't explicitly gives the update and clamping variables some value?

refer:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/fcb305874afb41aa9868747c1a993b8c5e6b259d/plugins/RandomVelocityPlugin.hh?fileviewer=file-view-default

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12046/use-of-class-randomvelocityprivateplugin-class/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `*Private` classes are part of the PIMPL idiom implementation (opaque pointers).

You can see the PIMPL idiom listed in the Gazebo [style guide](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contrib_code&cat=development#Style).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0